# pg_dump - no matching schemas were found - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to use pg_dump to dump a database, but am finding that I need to specify the schema. I want to avoid this as there are implications when the schema is specified (as documented in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), specifically this warning:

> When -n is specified, pg_dump makes no attempt to dump any other
> database objects that the selected schema(s) might depend upon.
> Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-schema
> dump can be successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.

The command I am using:
`pg_dump -v -f sds.bak -Fc -n 6  --quote-all-identifiers -h dbserver.host.com -p 5432 -U postgres -d "database-name"`

Output:

```
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: error: no matching schemas were found
```

Specifying 'schema' succeeds:
`pg_dump -v -f sds.bak -Fc -n 6  --quote-all-identifiers -h dbserver.host.com -p 5432 -U postgres -d "database-name" --schema public`

Information on the database and postgres versions:

\d:

```
          Name           |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges
-------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------
 database-name           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                        +
                         |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres               +
                         |          |          |             |             | "database-name"=CTc/postgres
```

\dn

```
postgres=> \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

`pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 14.3`

postgres version:

```
postgres=> select version();
                                                 version                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: The specified options include `-n 6`. Because of this, _pg_dump_ is looking for a schema named _6_, which I presume doesn't exist. That is the source of the error message.

Comment: Instead of vaguely referring to implications/issues and linking to a page, explicitly state the concerns so that others aren't left to guess.

Comment: Added detail around implications/issues of specifying schema

Answer (score 0):

@JohnH spotted the issue:

> The specified options include -n 6. Because of this, pg_dump is
> looking for a schema named 6, which I presume doesn't exist. That is
> the source of the error message. –

The intent was to use `-j 6`.